# Ideas for slicing a BeautifulSoup string to compartmentalize into certain categories?

Tags: python, string, split, beautifulsoup

So i'm in the process of doing some webscraping using BeautifulSoup and am given sequence of strings that are in this format:

`"PRICE. ADDRESS, PHONE#, " '<a href="WEBSITE">WEBSITE</a>`

to show you what I mean, here are two examples of how these strings are displayed in the HTML text.

```
"$10. 2109 W. Chicago Ave., 773-772-0406, "'<a href="http://www.theoldoaktap.com/">theoldoaktap.com</a>

"$9. 3619 North Ave., 773-772-8435, "'<a href="http://www.cemitaspuebla.com/">cemitaspuebla.com</a>
```

What's the best way to go this? It would've been easy if a comma followed the price (could've just done split(",") and addressed them by index, but what other alternatives do I have now? Can't split by periods because some addresses with directional streets have periods in the front (i.e. W. Chicago Ave).

Would the best solution be to split() and extract the first string (price), and then make a new string with the leftover indexes and then go about splitting by the comma (split(","))? Seems super non-python-y and i'm not sure that would work either.

**In the end, I want to end up with**

Price = $10

Location = 2109 W. Chicago Ave

Phone# = 773-772-0406

Website = http://www.theoldoaktap.com

thank you all in advance. my brain is fried.

Comment: You can parse it with a regular expression. The price and phone number are easy to parse, so you can pick out the address and website by matching everything besides the price and phone number.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
test = '"$10. 2109 W. Chicago Ave., 773-772-0406, "\'<a href="http://www.theoldoaktap.com/">theoldoaktap.com</a>'
extracted_entities = re.match(r'"\$(\d+)\. ([^,]+), ([\d-]+), "\'<a href="([^"]+)"', test)
print extracted_entities.groups()
```

Basically, since your strings are pretty rigidly formatted, you can simply use regular expression to extract out its components using some predetermined patterns. If you are going to do these types of projects often, I highly suggest studying regex, it's a very powerful tool!

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html